# How can I include data from another collection in my mongoose object?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am building an app with mongoDB and NodeJS with an Angular front end. I currently have users creating listings and then other users responding with bids within those listings, but want to include data of those responders. I am having a hard time including that user data in the bid create function and not sure why its not pulling.

Here is the listing schema

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var Bid = require('./bid');

var ListingSchema = new Schema({
  topic: String,
  description: String,
  budget: String,
  location: String,
  req1: String,
  req2: String,
  req3: String,
  created: String,
  dateReq: String,
  uid: String,
  bids: [Bid.schema]
})
```

This is how I currently create new listings

```
function create(req, res) {
  db.User.findById(req.user, function (err, user) {
    if (err) {console.log(err);}
    var newListing = new db.Listing(req.body);
    newListing.uid = user._id
    newListing.save(function (err, savedListing) {
      if (err) {
         res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
      } else {
        user.listings.push(newListing);
        user.save();
        res.json(savedListing);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

This is for new bids. For some reason, the db.User information is not getting pulled and my console log shows a blank object. (Yes I commented it out)

```
 function create(req, res) {
  //  db.User.findById(req.user, function (err, user) {
  //    console.log(req.user);
  //    if (err) {console.log(err);}
      db.Listing.findById(req.params.listingId, function(err, foundListing) {
       var newBid = new db.Bid(req.body);  // add data validation later
   //  newBid.uid = user._id
       foundListing.bids.push(newBid);
       foundListing.save(function(err, savedBid) {
         res.json(newBid);
       });
      });
   });
 };
```

Comment: what do you get when you log `req.user` and `user` object from callback

Comment: You do realize that this is not actually stored in "another collection". So either your question is titled incorrectly or you are missing the whole concept. Your included schema is "embedded" which means the data is contained within an array of the parent document, and nowhere else. You also need to show the definition of `Bid` and what is actually being sent to `req.body`

Answer (score 0):

try using user_id as a Object reference and populate it when needed your schema should be somewhat like this

```
var ListingSchema = new Schema({  topic: String,description: String, budget: String,  location: String,  req1: String,  req2: String,  req3: String,  created: String,  dateReq: String,//THIS CREATES A REFERENCE TO THE SCHEMA USER AND TO USE THIS YOU CAN POPULATE IT..  uid: {type:Schema.type.ObjectId,ref:User}, bids: [Bid.schema]})
```